# Why are my strawberry leaves turning yellow?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, fruits

About a week ago I planted a strawberry plant. New leaves are growing fine but the old big leaves are turning yellow. I don't know what the problem is. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is natural for plants to die back or drop leaves when they have been planted or re-planted, as they can be experiencing shock or are just adjusting to the new conditions. However, if the browning/yellowing continues, it is probably not happy with the location of the pot, or the nutrients in the soil. The new growth should indicate that it is quite happy though, so perhaps give it some more time and wait and see what happens.